# For Each loops to first build and then retrieve JTextField inputs

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, jbutton, jtextfield

I am still quite new to coding and I am hitting a bit of a wall right now.

I have an array of strings that I use in a loop to build a JLabel and a corresponding JTextField.

```
String[] textFieldList = {"Name", "Age", "Height", "weight"};

formPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(formPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
for (String tfL : textFieldList) {
    JLabel jl = new JLabel(tfL);
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField("");
    jtf.setName(tfL);
    formPanel.add(jl);
    formPanel.add(jtf);
}
addPanel.add(formPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I have a save button that I want to retrieve the all of entered values, so I am trying to use the same array to get the name of each JTextField by using the same array of strings to get the value of each text field.

I have not yet been able to successful build a loop that has worked for me yet.

```
saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
        for (String tfL : textFieldList) {              
            tfL.getText()                   
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a way that I can build the loop correctly to return the string results and can I test the returned values to see if they should be parsed as ints.

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is create jtextfield array and use normal loop instead enhanced .in your code you can't use `tfL.getText()`  because tfL is a String not a jtextfield .but in my code i have decalared `textfield array named  jtextf` so you can get values using `.getText()`

```
 JTextField[] jtextf;// global variable

 String[] textFieldList = {"Name", "Age", "Height", "weight"};
 jtextf=new JTextField[textFieldList.length];

 formPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(formPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    for (int i=0;i<textFieldList.length;i++) {

        JLabel jl = new JLabel(tfL);
        jtextf[i] = new JTextField("");
        jtextf[i].setName(textFieldList[i]);
        formPanel.add(jl);
        formPanel.add(jtextf[i]);
    }
}
```

when you want to retieve use

```
saveBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
        for (JTextField field: jtextf) {              
            field.getText()                   
        }
    }
});
```